# Does Socket.Bind be necessary for every situation about Socket programming?

Tags: c#, .net, sockets

Does Socket.Bind be necessary for every situation?
If no, what are the situation in which Socket.Bind must be used?
Any help? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every situation?  No.  It is required for servers, they need to call Listen() and that's meaningless unless Socket knows what IP-address to listen on.  Clients only have to call Connect(), that takes an IP-address.

The TcpListener class hides the Bind() call for you.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Actually, I want know the exact meaning of Bind()? Why Server needs Bind()?

Comment: @Jollian: I specifically addressed this in my answer.  I don't know how to make it any clearer if you don't explain why that wasn't clear.

Comment: OK. Maybe I asked a improper question, but your answer is right. Sorry for making you confused.
Thank you all the same.